# How to get json elements from http response string in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am new in json parsing from http api in python.Currently i have parsed http content as string  in python which have json object array my code is given bellow

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

apilink=urlopen("api link")


data=json.loads(apilink.read().decode())

print(data)
```

and my current output is

```
{'Message': 'Success', 'Data': '[{"Did":"c055c3d2f3314725b69965e6c55adb5b","InsertedDate":"2017-08-02 7:27:11 AM","UpdatedDate":"2017-08-02 9:33:16 AM","CreatedBy":"1","UpdatedBy":"1","Name":"Hello World","ModuleName":"Rpt_Hello_World","ApplicationName":"Asset Inventory","Published":"true","UserId":"1","PostProcessor":""}]', 'Status': 'Success'}
```

but i want to extract only attribute 'data' that is json array

```
'Data': '[{"Did":"c055c3d2f3314725b69965e6c55adb5b","InsertedDate":"2017-08-02 7:27:11 AM","UpdatedDate":"2017-08-02 9:33:16 AM","CreatedBy":"1","UpdatedBy":"1","Name":"Hello World","ModuleName":"Rpt_Hello_World","ApplicationName":"Asset Inventory","Published":"true","UserId":"1","PostProcessor":""}]'
```

desirble part is

[{"Did":"c055c3d2f3314725b69965e6c55adb5b","InsertedDate":"2017-08-02 7:27:11 AM","UpdatedDate":"2017-08-02 9:33:16 AM","CreatedBy":"1","UpdatedBy":"1","Name":"Hello World","ModuleName":"Rpt_Hello_World","ApplicationName":"Asset Inventory","Published":"true","UserId":"1","PostProcessor":""}]

kindly help me to solve this.
thank you

Comment: You can access `Data` like this `data['Data']`

Comment: If you want just the 'Data' attribute, try printing `data['Data']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a dictionary. Use dict indexing. You need the value associated with `Data`:

```
In [876]: data['Data']
Out[876]: '[{"Did":"c055c3d2f3314725b69965e6c55adb5b","InsertedDate":"2017-08-02 7:27:11 AM","UpdatedDate":"2017-08-02 9:33:16 AM","CreatedBy":"1","UpdatedBy":"1","Name":"Hello World","ModuleName":"Rpt_Hello_World","ApplicationName":"Asset Inventory","Published":"true","UserId":"1","PostProcessor":""}]'
```

This is a string. You can use `json.loads` one more time.

```
In [877]: json.loads(data['Data'])
Out[877]: 
[{'ApplicationName': 'Asset Inventory',
  'CreatedBy': '1',
  'Did': 'c055c3d2f3314725b69965e6c55adb5b',
  'InsertedDate': '2017-08-02 7:27:11 AM',
  'ModuleName': 'Rpt_Hello_World',
  'Name': 'Hello World',
  'PostProcessor': '',
  'Published': 'true',
  'UpdatedBy': '1',
  'UpdatedDate': '2017-08-02 9:33:16 AM',
  'UserId': '1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

thats simple

```
format: jsonName[attributename]

data['Data']
```